# Python-opencv import error, packages installed

Tags: python, opencv

I've installed opencv as said here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5c56e811bdd3> in <module>()
     11 
     12 import os
---> 13 import cv2
     14 import sys
     15 import copy

/jet/var/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 import importlib
      2 
----> 3 from .cv2 import *
      4 from .data import *
      5 

ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

already done:

`sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:amd64`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev

!apt-get update
!apt-get -y upgrade
!pip install opencv-python
!apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev -y
```

`!apt-get install python-opencv -y --allow-unauthenticated`

Comment: Do you try to run it on a headless machine (without gui)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

If this doesnt work try:

```
!apt-get update
!apt-get -y upgrade
!pip install opencv-python
!apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev -y
```

Comment: did you run these comands with sudo? Sorry, I should have mentioned this.

Comment: Also with !apt-get install python-opencv -y --allow-unauthenticated ? Next time please add to your question what you already tried :)